# Как добавить и редактировать переводы локализации

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно добавить строки перевода для темы woocommerce. Его файлы перевода нашел тут /wp-content/languages/plugins/.
У темы есть своя папка /wp-content/themes/mytheme/languages/

Если править переводы в /wp-content/languages/plugins/, то при обновлении плагина переводы затрутся?

Или как добавить переводы в /wp-content/themes/mytheme/languages/ и использовать из для переводов плагина woocommerce (функционал плагина)?

И какой из этих методов более верный, вроде как второй на мой взгляд.

Про poedit в курсе, сам сейчас использую Loco Translate с ней бы и хотелось продолжить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в вопросе смешаны два перевода: WooCommerce и вашей темы. Это разные строки (разные домены перевода), разные файлы, изменения в одном не влияют на другой.

В последних версиях WooCommerce появилась возможность безопасного сохранения своих переводов, независимого от обновления плагина. Для этого файл переводов Woocommerce должен быть размещен по следующему пути и иметь указанное имя:

```
/wp-content/languages/woocommerce/woocommerce-ru_RU.mo
```

Функционал woocommerce построен так, что многие шаблоны могут быть скопированы в папки темы и изменены. В том числе, могут быть изменены строки переводов, изменен домен перевода с woocommerce на домен темы. В этом случае для перевода  таких строк надо править файл .po темы, компилировать его в .mo и размещать в папках темы.

Для того, чтобы при обновлении темы ваш перевод текстового домена темы не слетел, надо создавать дочернюю тему. Это довольно просто. Подробнее об этом на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html).

В дочерней теме перевод должен быть размещен по такому пути:

```
/wp-content/themes/дочерняя-тема/languages/ru_RU.mo
```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Вопрос тогда возник по ней, создал я дочернюю тему, она открывается как и родительская (storefront), значит сделал все верно. Далее как и в родительской создать файл-копию /wp-content/themes/дочерняя-тема/inc/class-storefront.php где хочу добавить подключение bootstrap. Подключаю (добавляю строку кода, получается копия родительского файла + доп. строка), но в браузере его не вижу.

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос относительно модификации дочерних тем, с конкретным примером по storefront.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Установите Loco Translate, он позволит вам перевести и тему, и WC. После обновления переводы не удалятся, т.к. обновляется плагин, а файлы переводов остаются без изменений

Comment: да у него в вопросе написано, что он использует Loco ))

Comment: Тогда вообще не понимаю в чем вопрос

Comment: Ну честно говоря тема с дочерней темой мне нравится больше. С Loco я то ли не разобрался, но не нашел там возможности добавлять строки перевода.

Comment: Youtube вам в помощь